# Python SQL update query: string or integer address expected instead of instance instance

Tags: python, sql-server, sql-update, pyodbc, pypyodbc

I use Python 2.7 and pypyodbc in order to run SQL queries but whenever I run the update query using python,

```
cursor.execute("UPDATE tbl_User SET gender = ? WHERE id = 1", ['male'])
```

I get the error:

```
TypeError: string or integer address expected instead of instance instance
```

The same query works if I run it directly on SQL Server.

Comment: Are you able to get it to work without passing the parameter and hard coding it into the UPDATE statement?

Comment: you mean something like that:
cursor.execute("UPDATE tbl_User SET gender = 'male' WHERE id = 1")?

Comment: Yes, just to ensure the code is executable through pypyodbc. :)

Comment: I get the error :/ 
but as I said, it does work if I run it directly on SQL Server

Answer (score 3):

The problem was I didn't put a semicolon at the end of the query. The solution is:

```
cursor.execute("UPDATE tbl_User SET gender = ? WHERE id = 1;", ['male'])
```

Comment: You may want to amend your answer and tag it to include what database you're using, since this would seem to be database specific.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. SQL Server's really adamant about those semi-colons, but it'd been a while since I've used it, so that didn't pop out to me.

Answer (score 0):

How about that:

```
gender = 'male'
cursor.execute("UPDATE tbl_User SET gender = {:s} WHERE id = 1".format(gender))
```

Also make sure that the python version of sqlite and the one used by the SQL Server are the same. For the python one type:

```
import sqlite3
print(sqlite3.sqlite_version)
```

Comment: I get the error:
pypyodbc.ProgrammingError: (u'42S22', u"[42S22] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Invalid column name 'male'.")